# iOS: When layoutIfNeeded() is called on a specific subview, it is not displayed on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, view, autolayout

I am dynamically adding and displaying a custom view. At this time, the custom view has subviews.

When showing a custom view and additionally showing internal subviews, I am curious as to why the position of that view is not reflected in the parent view if layoutIfNeeded() is called on a specific subview.

Below is my code.

```
final class RotationCardView: UIView {
  ...
  private lazy var gradientLabel = GradientAnimatedLabel()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    ...
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) { nil }

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
  }

  func setGradientLabel() {
    let minimumTopSpacing = 5.0
    gradientLabel.text = "# cute cat card"
    gradientLabel.alpha = 0
    addSubview(gradientLabel)
    let gradientLabelBottomConstraint = gradientLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: bottomAnchor,
    constant: minimumTopSpacing - gradientLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height/2)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      gradientLabelBottomConstraint,
      gradientLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)])
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

I added this custom view to the ViewController's view: After that I have logic to call setGradientLabel() when the button is pressed.

When I call setGradientLabel(), the gradinetLabel is displayed after being laid out on the screen.

But what I'm curious about here is when gradientLabel.layoutIfNeeded() is used instead of self.layoutIfNeeded() within the setGradientLabel() function.

```
func setGradientLabel() {
  ...    
  // [comment1]
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    gradientLabelBottomConstraint,
    gradientLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)])
  gradientLabel.layoutIfNeeded() // gradientLabel is not displayed on the screen.
}
```

As shown in the code snippet above, if I call layoutIfNeeded() of gradientLayer inside the setGradientLabel() function, [comment1] The layout added below is not applied and is not displayed on the screen.

The picture below is the view hierarchy.

[image]

In the above code, in order for the gradientLabel I wanted to be displayed directly in the RotationCardView, is it desirable to call layoutIfNeeded() on the view to which the gradientLabel constraint has been added?

Comment: Well you answered it yourself - in order for a view to lay out its children you'd call layoutIfNeeded on it instead of any of its children right

Comment: It's not clear why you need to be calling `layoutIfNeeded()` at all. What exactly are you trying to do? You appear to have left out parts of your code (`...`)?

Comment: @DonMag  The " ... " in the setGradientLabel() function is a shorthand for inside the RotationCardView's setGradientLabel() function in the very early code snippet. I was curious why self.layoutIfNeeded() was performed well inside RotationCardView's setGradientLabel(), but gradientLabel.layoutIfNeeded() was not.

Comment: @Petar Oh, in order for a view to immediately place its children, layoutIfNeeded() must be called on the parent's view instead of the child. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @sweetSwift - there *are* specific cases where `layoutIfNeeded()` needs to be called, but it's not that common. If your use-case is working, great... but if you want to show a more complete example of what you're trying to do, we may find that it can be done with a more "automatic" approach.